# Prevent memory overflow

Tags: php, memory, curl

At some point in my php script that makes use of curl, the following error shows up: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to
allocate 77824 bytes) in"... It points out this part of the script: "$s = curl_exec($c);"

What is the problem? And how to settle it down?

Answer (score 8):

In this case, your server is misconfigured.

> Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes

200 kilobytes of RAM per script are not enough for most PHP scripts. The standard in my experience is 8 MB minimum; 16 MB is normal. A blog system like WordPress (it is admittedly fat, but still one of the most popular blog systems around) chokes on 8 MB and runs half-way decently with 16.

You should change the `memory_limit` value in your php.ini. If you're on shared hosting, demand that the provider increase it to at least 8M, better 16M or more. If they deny, get out of there: It's sub-standard hosting.

Answer (score 5):

you are tying to allocate more memory than the heap can handle

set your limit higher, for xample

at the top of the script::

```
ini_set("memory_limit","10M");
```

or in your php.ini

```
memory_limit = 10M
```

this set your memory_limit to 10M

Answer (score 1):

`ini_set()` is probably better than setting something in `php.ini`.  If you've got a specific application you *know* needs more than the standard memory - then it's fine to increase the memory limit for that application.  You want to be really careful opening up all your code to having a higher memory limit though.

That said, if you set `memory_limit` to 0, there is no memory limit & the script will use as much memory as it needs (and the system can give it).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

1. edit your `php.ini` file and change the line that says `memory_limit = .25M` so that it says

   `memory_limit = 16M`
2. make sure you are calling

   `curl_close($c);`

   consistently.

If you want to include a larger code snippet, maybe we can see where you have memory leaks.